# Can you write (with and ink pen) on hydrophobic paper?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions

Would the ink be repelled from the paper or prone to smearing?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27384/what-forces-hold-ink-on-paper

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what your ink is based on. If it can be washed off ordinary paper using water, it will be repelled on hydrophobic paper. However, if it can't, it has a chance of staying on.

Note that the paper in particular might repel *all* or *most* liquids, not just water. In this case, the ink has a very low chance of staying on the paper.

Comment: Most inks are hydrophobic I believe if we're talking printer inks or pen inks.